# Lost Word Document

Tags: microsoft-word, microsoft-office

I'm not sure if anyone can help with this but I've been typing like mad all day in Word (office for Mac 2016) and I have been saving the document regularly, like every 15-20 minutes because I have never trusted Office. I got a random error (I wish I could remember it but I wasn't even using the document at the time, it was simply sitting in the background) and of course Word crashes stating it can't save my document. I though this would not be a huge issue because I've saved it 100 times today but it has literally removed the physical file from my drive and any record of it existing in the recent documents list. Is there anything I can do or check to recover this file?

Comment: Check if in your folder you have a hidden recent file whose name starts with `~` and the rest looks partially like yours. This might be a draft file. Copy it elsewhere and try to open it.

Comment: On Windows, with default settings, Office will autosave unsaved documents at `%USERPROFILE%\AppData\Local\Microsoft\Office\UnsavedFiles` and keep them for four days. You might look up the location for this on your Mac in the Word options.